# Uso do pandas.concat()

Tags: python, pandas

Eu estou usando o `pandas.concat()` pra concatenar dois df que eu dei `pandas.merge()`

```py
df3 =pd.merge(joi,df, on=['cpf'], how='outer', suffixes=['', '_'], indicator=True)
klog = df3.loc[df3['_merge'] == 'right_only',['cod empresa','conta capital_','nome empresa','nome']]
klog2= df3.loc[df3['_merge'] == 'left_only',['Núcleo','Nome Cliente','cpf','conta capital']]
kong = pd.concat([klog2,klog],axis=1)
```

O problema é que ele não esta juntando ambos pelas colunas e sim pelo index, mesmo eu passando o argumento de eixo, como eu poderia fazer pra **juntar** um df **ao lado** do outro em vez de **juntar em pilha**??
um df nao tem a mesma coluna que o outro, porem na documentação ele dfs com colunas diferentes como exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você fazer isso precisa primeiro zerar os indexes dos dfs. Ajuste o seu código para:

```
df3 =pd.merge(joi,df, on=['cpf'], how='outer', suffixes=['', '_'], indicator=True)
klog = df3.loc[df3['_merge'] == 'right_only',['cod empresa','conta capital_','nome empresa','nome']]
klog2= df3.loc[df3['_merge'] == 'left_only',['Núcleo','Nome Cliente','cpf','conta capital']]

klog.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
klog2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

kong = pd.concat([klog2,klog],axis=1)
```

Comment: Obrigado @Evilmaax, eu consegui chegar no resultado que eu queria trocando o nome da coluna 'conta capital_' pra 'conta capital' e fazendo um merge neles usando essa coluna como parametro, mas acho q com o seu metodo tambem iria funcionar